# How to design one user "likes" another?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I would imagine this is kind of like friends, but doesn't need to be two-way. So like this:

```
from_user   to_user
-------------------
John        Mary
Mary        John
John        Susan
Mary        Dave
```

I was curious if there were any issues with doing it as shown below.

```
user1       user2      mutuality 
--------------------------------
John        Mary       2
John        Susan      1
Mary        Dave       1
```

The second seems like it would have more complicated queries and checks, but wouldn't it end up saving space? For example, if Susan ends up falling for John one day, you'd check user2 for Susan and user1 for John. If it exists, update the mutuality to 2. If not, insert a new row [Susan, John, 1]. Something like that?

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose the first method. You will not end up saving enough space with the second method to be an issue. Since each choice (like) is an action, having a separate record to store that action matches the work flow. John likes Mary, add a record. Mary likes John, add another record. Mary no longer likes John, delete that single record. This is easier to maintain (for me). I find keeping things in smaller granular parts keeps it simple.

In terms of design, I would recommend that instead of using string names in the `likes` table, you should have a `users` table with each user have a primary key id (unique). This way, users can modify names without breaking the relationships.

The table data would look like this:

```
Users table
id Name
1 John
2 Mary
3 Susan
4 Dave

Likes table
From To
1    2
2    1
1    3
2    4
```

The tables would have the following structure

```
users
-----
id (integer autoincrement)
name (varchar)

likes
-----
id (integer autoincrement)
fromid (integer)
toid (integer)
```

The sql would look like this to produce the list

```
SELECT f.name as fromName, t.name as toName
FROM (likes JOIN users AS f ON likes.fromid = f.id) 
JOIN users AS t ON likes.toid = t.id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The second method allows the following anomaly:

```
user1       user2      mutuality 
--------------------------------
John        Mary       2
Mary        John       1
```

Do John and Mary like each other mutually (as implied by the first row), or just Mary likes John uni-directionally (as implied by the second row)?

The first method doesn't suffer from such inconsistencies, and data integrity is generally more important than saving some space.

---

BTW, if you introduce an integer [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) and reference it from the junction table (instead of the actual names), the junction table will become much leaner, negating much of the space advantage of the second method.